# Updating UILabel and clearing it?

Tags: objective-c, uilabel

I have a UILabel that I start at "0" and then as my game progresses I call the below code to add "1" to the score each time a button is pressed. This all works fine.

```
playerOneScore.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[playerOneScore.text intValue]+1];
```

My problem is that when the game ends and the user presses the "Replay" button. This replay button sets the label back to "0" by calling this.

```
playerOneScore.text = @"0";
```

But then when the game progresses my label jumps from "0" to where it had initially left off + 1. What am I doing wrong here? Not making sense.

Any help would be very grateful! Thank you!

More code requested (simplified):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    playerOneScore.text = @"0";
}

-(IBAction)touchDown {
    if (playerOneTurn == YES) {

        if (button1.touchInside == YES) {

        playerOneScore.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[playerOneScore.text intValue]+1];

        }
    }
}


-(void) replayGame {

        playerOneScore.text = @"0";
}
```

Comment: You need to show more code.

Comment: There you go @fumoboy007 Simplified it a bit to make it easy. It's bizarre. After i "replayGame" and then press the +1 button the label jumps to a super high number?

Comment: @SeanHerman: try setting it to nil, then to 0 to be sure the old value is being removed.

Comment: I would rather create a class variable to hold score and set its value to the label. See if that helps.

Comment: I'm guessing that "replayGame" is being called in a different instance of your object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure what's going on, but I would suggest using a separate NSInteger property to track the score. Then override the property setter to update the label text.

Add the property to your interface or a private category:

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSInteger score;
```

Then override the setter:

```
- (void)setScore:(NSInteger)value {
    _score = value;
    playerOneScore.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", value];
}
```

Then in your action, update the score and label using the new property:

```
-(IBAction)touchDown {
    if (playerOneTurn == YES) {
        if (button1.touchInside == YES) {
            self.score += 1;    
        }
    }
}
```

Note that I haven't compiled or tested this code, but it should be close.

EDIT: fixed typo in setter